# Press and Hold Hardware Buttons in Appium

Tags: appium

Currently I am using:

```
Driver.longPressKeyCode(KEYCODE_BUTTON_R1);
```

To press the R1 Key on my device. This works, however, it doesn't press it for long enough. Is there a command to set the duration of the longPressKeyCode event, to maybe hold the button down for a second?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested we ended up using a batch file which ran:

adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 1 311 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0 0 0
adb shell sleep 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 1 311 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event3 0 0 0

we found the events using

adb shell getevent

This works perfectly for barcode scanning, and pressing and holding a hardware button.